# Wordpress switch statement

Tags: php, wordpress, switch-statement

Can anyone help me with a switch statement for wordpress 3.9.2?

Users login on the frontend then links are echoed out depending on the user ID.

Code below uses if else, ideally I would like to use switch statement as there will be more users in the long run.

Thanks,

```
<?php
$user_id = get_current_user_id();
if ($user_id == 1) {
    echo '<p><a href="/page1/">My Area 1</a></p>'; }
elseif ($user_id == 2) {
    echo '<p><a href="/page2/">My Area 2</a></p>';
}
elseif ($user_id == 3) {
    echo '<p><a href="/page3/">My Area 3</a></p>';
} else {
}
```

?>

Answer (score 1):

```
switch($user_id) {
case 1:
    echo '<p><a href="/page1/">My Area 1</a></p>';
    break;
case 2:
    echo '<p><a href="/page2/">My Area 2</a></p>';
    break;
case 3:
    echo '<p><a href="/page3/">My Area 3</a></p>';
    break;
default:
    // Do anything
    break;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but it doesn't get the user_id :(

Answer (score 1):

I would propose a different method rather than using condition checks.

Build an array like:

```
$arr = array( array( "url1", "str1" ), array( "url2", "str2" ), array( "url3", "str3" ) );
```

then based on the user id you would echo like this:

```
$user_id = get_current_user_id();
echo '<p><a href="'.$arr[$user_id][0].'">'.$arr[$user_id][1].'</a></p>';
```

This allows you to scale for any number of users. To make the code more efficient you could store the array in the database and pull it when required.

Comment: Very interested in this solution!

Comment: Iam logged in as user ID 1 but getting str2? Is that correct? 

Thanks,

Comment: Because array starts with 0, `$arr[0]` means user1 and `$arr[1]` means user2. You could either put some dummy values for `$arr[0]` or pass `$user_id-1` to the array.

Comment: It would be nice if this is accepted as the answer if it has met your requirement.